# SQLite not printing

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I'm trying to learn SQL through "Learn SQL the Hard Way" and I am having difficulty with the the command prompt. In particular, I am having trouble with the [3rd exercise](http://sql.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex3.html).

I am able to create a database from ex2.sql by calling

```
sqlite3 ex3.db < ex2.sql
```

This should build a database with the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name TEXT,
    last_name TEXT,
    age INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE pet (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    breed TEXT,
    age INTEGER,
    dead INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE person_pet (
    person_id INTEGER,
    pet_id INTEGER
);
```

Calling .schema on sqlite3 ex3.db prints out exactly this.

Then I use ex3.sql which has the contents:

```
INSERT INTO person (id, first_name, last_name, age)
    VALUES (0, "Zed", "Shaw", 37);

INSERT INTO pet (id, name, breed, age, dead)
    VALUES (0, "Fluffy", "Unicorn", 1000, 0);

INSERT INTO pet VALUES (1, "Gigantor", "Robot", 1, 1);
```

I insert to ex3.db by saying:

```
sqlite3 -echo ex3.db < ex3.sql
```

According to the book, this should insert the values from ex3.sql into ex3.db while printing out what it is doing. However, when I type the above into cmd it prints nothing. And when I call

```
sqlite3 ex3.db
select * from person;
```

it still shows nothing. My guess is that either the database file is not updating, something with my install went wrong, or I'm messing something else up here. Appreciate any help that can be given.

Comment: What happens if you do `sqlite3 ex3.db < ex3.sql`?

Comment: Nothing. It skips a line then goes to the next prompt.

Comment: Open up `ex3.sql`, does it still have your commands in?

Comment: Thank you. I'm an idiot. I forgot to save my changes to ex3.sql in my text editor so ex3.sql was a blank file. Thanks for the help.

Comment: When a question is answered you press the green tick next to the answer (and if you're feeling nice an upvote). You don't need to add answered to the title!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command:

`sqlite3 -echo ex3.db < ex3.sql`

Is used to print what is in the `ex3.sql` file as it is executed. If nothing is displayed then nothing will be in the file! This means that it will be a problem with the `ex3.sql` file, such that it is either empty or corrupt.